# BackgroundWorker support cancelation

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I use BackgroundWorker but have problem with reporting cancellation:

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
worker.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
{
    expensiveMethod();
}
```

DoWork should periodically check if cancellation request is pending. How to do this, if I cant modify expensiveMethod?

Comment: is there a way to cancel the expensive method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot modify your `expensiveMethod()` then there is no direct way to process cancellation.

If `expensiveMethod()` is working on some big chunk of data, maybe you can split that data and process smaller (not so lengthy) chunks in a loop and after each iteration check for the cancel flag. Something like this:

```
//...
worker.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
{
   do
   {
       provideNextChunk();
       expensiveMethod();
   }
   while (hasMoreData && !args.Cancel);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

BackgroundWorker is designed to work with threads that actually CAN respond to cancellation requests. If your expensiveMethod() cannot do it, I advise you to use [System.Threading.Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bkb1k2x8.aspx) instead. Run it as [background](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx) thread, and use [Thread.Abort()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ty8d3wta.aspx) to cancel it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx). Tasks uses threads from the ThreadPool (such as BackgroundWorker), but they support cancellation (via [CancellationToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.aspx)), without the need of exceptions.

Comment: This would be a good option but the OP says he cannot modify `expensiveMethod();` which counts this out.